# How to specify -march=native with %%cython

Tags: python, ipython, cython

In ipython I can do the following:

```
%%cython --compile-args=-Ofast
def f(x):
    return 2.0*x
```

But how can I add `-march=native` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--compile-args` flag can be passed several times, as can be seen in the help by running `%%cython?` in a notebook cell:

```
-c COMPILE_ARGS, --compile-args COMPILE_ARGS
                    Extra flags to pass to compiler via the
                    `extra_compile_args` Extension flag (can be specified
                    multiple times).
```

The final answer would therefore be:

```
%%cython --compile-args=-Ofast --compile-args=-march=native

def f(x):
    return 2.0*x
```